# Extract sample of values from an interval

Tags: r

I have a data set with 30 values. Data for example:

```
value <- c(3.00, 3.30, 5.10, 2.09, 7.04,
   1.07, 7.33, 2.15, 3.27, 3.94, 3.07, 3.46, 5.45, 2.99, 7.89,
   1.67, 5.33, 2.56, 3.45, 3.76, 3.20, 3.50, 3.10, 2.67, 4.04,
   4.07, 3.33, 3.15, 2.27, 3.90) 

data <- data.frame(value)
```

Using quantiles I can select values between the percentages 25%, 50%, 75%.

For example:

```
data$value <- data$value[data$value>=quantile(data$value)[4]]
newvalue <- data$value[data$value>=quantile(data$value)[4]]
data$value <- sample(newvalue, dim(data)[1], replace=T)
```

I would like to extract random values in certain range, the values "greater than 3 and less than 3.94".

And then I would like to replace the column "values" (30 rows) with these random values (> 3 and < 3.94).

The expected result is this:

```
value <- c(3.00, 3.30, 3.76, 3.20, 3.10,
   3.00, 3.46, 3.76, 3.27, 3.94, 3.07, 3.46, 3.76, 3.46, 3.90,
   3.30, 3.33, 3.94, 3.45, 3.76, 3.20, 3.50, 3.10, 3.20, 3.10,
   3.15, 3.33, 3.15, 3.00, 3.90)
```

how to do that best?

Thank you!

Comment: The code for the quantiles is working, yes. However, I would like to extract values of a given range.

Comment: no , I did not get you. Could you show us your expected output? `extract 25% of random values in certain range,` so you want to extract them from the `value` column itself ?

Comment: Ok, @Ronak. I put the result that I hope. Thank you.

Comment: yes, that is helpful. what is 25 % here ? These are just 30 random values in the range 3 to 3.94, right?

Comment: Yes, it would be so random values replaced between >3 to <3.94. 25% is the number of values in this range in my database.
I will delete this part. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about generating a `seq`uence of numbers from 3.00 to 3.94 and then selecting randomly 30 from them

```
sample(seq(3.00, 3.94, 0.01), nrow(data))

#[1] 3.01 3.80 3.65 3.84 3.05 3.25 3.49 3.68 3.27 3.24 3.03 3.28 3.42 3.30 3.82 
#[16] 3.39 3.67 3.71 3.78 3.72 3.02 3.23 3.64 3.10 3.48 3.34 3.09 3.38 3.74 3.93
```

**Update**

If you want to select it from the dataset, you can try

```
sample(data[data$value > 3.0 & data$value < 3.94, "value"],nrow(data), replace = T)
#[1] 3.46 3.15 3.76 3.50 3.30 3.30 3.20 3.30 3.27 3.07 3.46 3.46 3.30 3.15 3.46 
#[16] 3.27 3.45 3.46 3.27 3.76 3.45 3.27 3.45 3.90 3.76 3.10 3.45 3.10 3.10 3.33
```

Comment: I understood. However, I wish they were extracted values of the dataset.

Comment: Updated the answer. Giving the value from the data set.